# Wordpress publishes the articles and gives error 404 for the first 10 minutes

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, publish, article

I have a big issue with Wordpress.

I write the articles and then I click on "publish". If I enter as an admin from Wordpress (wp.website.com...) everything looks fine but I just saw that if I enter as a normal viewer (www.website.com...) the website does not load properly for the first 10 minutes or so and it gives a 404 error.

After 10 minutes the error stops and you can see the article properly.

Why does it happen?

I think Wordpress should wait 10 minutes to publish the article or even better, publish it immediately without giving that error.

What solutions can I apply?

Comment: Do you have a cache plugin running on the site?

Comment: I am asking one of my coworkers, and he said tomorrow he will check that info. Sorry guys for not answering this immediately. But this is very important and I will update with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

disable all plugins and check again  if this proplem stopped i think its come form some plugin in your site if this work good 
 try to active plugins 1 by 1 and check again pleas if work with you tell me here